# What do I need to install for Redis in a celery+flask based app?

Tags: python, redis, pip

I am following [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) blog to implement background tasks using celery in python flask. At the very end of the article it says:

> Now you need to run the three processes required by this application,
>   so the easiest way is to open three terminal windows. **On the first
>   terminal run Redis. You can just install Redis according to the
>   [download instructions](https://redis.io/download) for your operating system**, but if you are on a
>   Linux or OS X machine, I have included a small script that downloads,
>   compiles and runs Redis as a private server:

The download instruction leads to the redis download page. It has links for client as well as the (I believe) server. But I already have run `pip install redis` on my system and I'm not sure if that downloaded redis client or server. What did `pip install redis` install and which download link should I use to run the redis process as described in the article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `pip install redis` installs Python bindings for Redis, it does not install Redis (either a client or a server) itself.

To find the project that is installed when you run `pip install redis`, check the project's PyPI page (https://pypi.org/project/redis/). This points you to the package on Github (https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py). The first thing the Readme says is:

> The Python interface to the Redis key-value store.

So, this is not the Redis key-value store, it's just a Python interface to Redis.

> redis-py requires a running Redis server. See Redis's quickstart for installation instructions.

Once the Redis server is running (note, you want a Redis server, not a Redis cilent!), redis-py gives you Python functions to interact with the Redis server. But you will need to follow the quickstart instructions to get Redis up and running.

(Note that this is a common pattern for PyPI projects; for example, `pip install elasticsearch` or `pip install pandoc` do not install elasticsearch or pandoc binaries, they install Python APIs to those programs.)